# nosuchelement:Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//body/div[@id='root']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]"}

Tags: html, css, automation, selenium-chromedriver

can anyone help there is no such identifier how can i click this button this error arises when i use this code

```js
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[@id='root']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]")).click();
```

```html
<div class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root jss18 MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false" style="padding-right: 0px;" xpath="1">
  <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root jss19" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
          <path d="M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z"></path></svg>
  <div class="MuiListItemText-root jss21">Loan Management</div>
  <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></div>
```

here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    //System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("abc@abc");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"password\"]")).sendKeys("abc");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'root\']/div/main/div[2]/div/form/button/span[1]")).click();
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[@id='root']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]")).click();
    
    //Select dropdown = new Select(staticdropdown);
//  dropdown.selectByIndex(0);
    //System.out.println(dropdown.getFirstSelectedOption().getText());
    
}
```

Comment: There is no element with ID `root`, so that's why it's not found

Comment: @Justinas i'm copying xpath by right clicking this html code. Sorry but guide me i'm new in this automation testing

Comment: We need to see the rest of the HTML to know what xpath/selector to use. Also, please share the code you are running to see if it is a timing issue or something else.]

Comment: @C.Peck i've added the code

Comment: Please add a proper title to help understand the issue you are facing. For e.g: Error nosuchelement when using selenium.